# Problem DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN on Ubuntu 20 when using VPN

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, vpn, bug-reporting

When I connect to a VPN and enter certain sites an error `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN` appears.

I have already tried to go to `/etc/resolv.conf` and add `8.8.8.8`, `8.8.4.4` and VPN domain and it keeps falling all the time. It doesn't happen in Linux Mint.

also websites will not open after a "refresh"

If nobody can help me I will have to leave the distro which is a shame, so I ask the community for help.

Comment: Does the site open if you refresh it?  Have same on my system using VPN, but sites always open after refresh/reload of site.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but the trouble originated with the VPN provider. IPVanish changed their OpenVPN set up.

IPVanish provides OpenVPN configuration files for hundreds of servers. These are imported/created through Network Connections. For years I needed to access the advanced options and select "use a TCP connection". One day TCP connections failed resulting in the DNS probe comming up dry - no connection. I had a very frustrating experience with their technical contact,with no resolution. At the end of the day, I deleted all the VPN connections and re-installed using UPD. Now all works fine with one exception... I can only connect to about 25% of their servers.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Try below.
sudo nano /etc/hosts
# Add below line for example.
# Change IP and Domain accordingly
# IP Domain
192.168.8.1 sitedomain.com
# Save this file and try to open your site.
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution similar to the first "`sudo nano /etc/hosts`"

is to edit the `/etc/resolv.conf`
with `sudo vi /etc/resolv.conf` or another editor you prefer

and add before the `naveserver` your other nameservers you like to listen.

by that you dont need to add manually all domains just the server you like to listen

e.g.

those lines i edit
`nameserver 10.24.....`
`nameserver 8.8.8.8`
those where before
`nameserver 127.0.0....`
`option eds0 trust-ad`
`search`